# MinGW Compiler Fail download

Tags: macos, installation, error-handling, compiler-errors, download

I'm trying to download MinGW Compiler on my M1 MacBook Pro through the terminal but when I write the command "arch -x86_64 ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/ins tall/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null" this error comes up: The requested URL returned error: 400
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: tall. Can someone Please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in the url, should be https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install